# RxJava2 with Socket.IO in Android

Tags: socket.io, rx-java2, rx-android

I am experimenting/learning RxJava2, RxAndroid2 and Socket.IO 1.0. So far the samples, books and tutorials available are all related to RxJava 1 and there has been a major change in RxJava2 which is rewritten according Reactive Streams standard. In Socket.IO all I need is to establish a connection and then wait for any events like `EVENT_CONNECT`, `EVENT_CONNECT_ERROR` and `EVENT_CONNECTING`, so I could know when the internet is dropped and Socket.IO is trying to re-establish the connection. Then I need another event listener like `MESSAGE` to know when message is arriving.

After going through RxJava2 documentation, all I knew is that it can be implemented with `Flowable` and `CompositeDisposable` but I don't know how to use them and besides this what could be the best approach. Even the book which I have purchased last night covers only RxJava 1.

Comment: I have finally found a great resource, a presentation from an author of some Java books. It has helped me in its implementation. :) Here is the link https://www.slideshare.net/yfain/reactive-thinking-in-java-with-rxjava2

Comment: The book "Learning RxJava" from Packt addresses RxJava 2.

Comment: Oh thats great... Sadly I missed their discount offer few days back. :(